# How do I best resolve an offset position into a line, col position in a vscode DefinitionProvider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm porting my atom package for ensime integration into a vscode one.

When trying to do the definitionProvider I struck a problem. ensime-server gives me absolute character positions but the DefinitionProvider protocol demands row,col. This hasn't been a problem as long as I have the document since I then can simply do `document.positionAt(offset)` and `document.offsetAt(position)` but in the scope a definitionProvider, I haven't actually opened up any Document yet and I don't think I should just to resolve the position since it's also used by vscode for hovering info…

Here's my wip: https://github.com/hedefalk/ensime-vscode/commit/57ed65f06e64e7f8969e08a8ac676d2c241287d1#diff-ee758fbdcafb036ed84d706f8b6f42a1R19

What's my best option of resolving a character offset into the vscode.Position required? Is there a quick file reader I could use? I really don't want to open up files externally.

Comment: Did you find a solution?